# how to add Image.file as backgroundimage of Circle avatar

Tags: flutter

Into my app users cant pick up picture and place it into the app, not the image that I need to place is a background image of the circleavatar.
I built throught the package: image_picker a screen where image can be picked up by the phone but as I cant place the image into the backgroundof the circle avatar.
this is my code:

```
File _image;
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  Future getImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);


    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
      }
    });
  }
```

and build method:

```
_image == null ? CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 60,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                  child: Text(IfUserProfile.firstname[0],),
                ): CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 60,
                backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                child: Image.file(_image),),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 4,
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: getImage,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [Icon(Icons.add_a_photo,color: Colors.white,size: 18,),
                      Text('   Aggiungi un immagine profilo',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10,color: Colors.white),),
                      ]),
                ),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CircleAvatar` has `backgroundImage` attribute. try like below,

```
CircleAvatar(
    ..
    backgroundImage: FileImage(_image),
),
```

Comment: of course it doesnt work. because backgroundImage: just accept AssetImage or NetworkImage

Comment: It doesn't work!

Comment: Since `FileImage` extends `ImageProvider` and `backgroundImage`'s type `ImageProvider`, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

CircleAvatar has an attribute just for this.
Try:

```
CircleAvatar(
  ...
  backgroundImage: ...,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this widget instead to do the same job:

```
ClipPath(
      clipper: ShapeBorderClipper(shape:  const CircleBorder()),
      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
      child: Image.asset(
             'assets/images/tutorial_1_bg.png',
              height: 200.0,
              width: 200.0,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ));
```